# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths causing Database.SetInitializer to not work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-4.3

My code-first database was working great.  If I made a change to my database context the database would be updated the next time I started the application.  But then I added some models to the database and got this error when I restarted my application:

`Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_OrderDetails_Orders_OrderId' on table 'OrderDetails' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.`

One of the weird things is that if I start the application up again without changing anything, I then get this error:

`Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.`

To get the first error to happen again, I have to delete my .mdf and .ldf files (the database) and replace just the .mdf file with a copy from my revision history.

**Why in the world is this happening?**

---

*For reference:*

My Global.asax.cs file has this within the `Application_Start()` method:

`Database.SetInitializer<EfDbContext>(new EfDbContextInitializer());`

Which looks like this:

```
public class EfDbContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EfDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(EfDbContext context)
    {
        var orders = new List<Order>
            {
                . . .
            };
        orders.ForEach(s => context.Orders.Add(s));
         . . . etc. . .
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My connection string from `Web.config`:

`<add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=pos;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|pos.mdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

And, finally, my Order and OrderDetails models (what the first error is directly referencing):

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

    public int EstablishmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Establishment Establishment { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public int OrderDetailId { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Update / Note: If I comment out `public int OrderId { get; set; }` in my OrderDetail class, the project starts up fine (although I do not get the desired ability to add an `OrderId` (of course).

Comment: Are you defining any mapping instructions anywhere?

Comment: The FK in the error doesn't need to be the origin of the problem. It is the FK where error was fired. You need to track your changes and find the real reason for the error.

Comment: @JTMon I am using Ninject to bind my interface and the repository `kernel.Bind<IOrderProcessor>().To<EfOrderRepository>();`.

Comment: I used to count on EF to do the mapping for me but now I rely more and more on Fluent API to specify the exact mapping I want.  You can do this even if just to try and localise the problem.  It is a bit more work but you gain in flexibility plus there are certain things you can only do with the fluent API.  So I suggest you define the mappings for these two classes manually and see what happens.
P.S.: what kind of constraints did the generated database have on it as far as these 2 tables are concerned?

Comment: @JTMon Before I added the mentioned models, they did not exist in the database at all - so they would have no constraints for these two tables.  I was just now adding them to my EfDbContext.  I have never used Fluent API to specify exact mapping -- I guess it's time to learn.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem is caused by a possible cyclic cascading delete. This can happen in many forms, but it comes down to a record being deleted by two or more cascading delete rules in one time.

For example, lets say you have Parent table and two Child tables. Then you also have another table which is linked to both Child tables:

```
Parent
------
ParentId
Name

ChildOne
--------
ChildOneId
ParentId
Name

ChildTwo
--------
ChildTwoId
ParentId
Name

SharedChild
-----------
SharedChildId
ChildOneId
ChildTwoId
Name
```

When you delete a record from the Parent table, it is possible this delete will cascade to both ChildOne *and* ChildTwo. These two deletes can then further cascade to SharedChild and here we get the problem: two paths trying to delete the same record from SharedChild.

I'm not saying your situation is exactly the same, but one way or another, you have something similar going on. To solve this, you can decide to let one branch be allowed to cascade further down the chain and prevent it in the other chain.

The reason you get this error only the first time you run your app and then every time you delete the database, is because (I believe) Entity Framework stops generating the database at the point the error occurs and you are left with an incomplete database. That's why you're getting the other error in the other situations.

If you need more help resolving the cyclic cascading delete, you will probably need to show your entire datamodel and its relations.

Comment: The part about Entity Framework stopping the database generation at the point of the error explains a lot of confusion.  Thank you for that.  I don't think anything else in my datamodel is tying into the relationships involved in the mentioned two tables - but I could be wrong.  https://github.com/ecnalyr/POS/tree/Changing-Order-Processor <-- that is a link to my latest commit of this branch on GitHub that is right where I am at with my current problem.  Maybe that can show all the details of my datamodel (it may be rather lengthy for a post here)?

Comment: Note that the above git commit works when you start the app, that is because I have the line: `public int OrderId { get; set; }` commented out within my OrderDetail class.  Please forgive that.

Comment: How about this (only had a quick look): delete an Establishment. That deletes Products and Orders. The deletion of a product cascades down to OrderDetail. The deletion of an Order cascades down to OrderDetail as well.

Comment: Congratulations on knowing more about my design than myself.  What stands out to me as kind of dumb would be deleting a Product ultimately resulting in the deletion of an OrderDetail.  Why would a business ever want to delete history of an OrderDetail?  Thank you for opening my eyes.  Now I need to figure out how to redesign this nonsense.

Comment: @Ecnalyr, you generally wouldn't.  That is why you shouldn't use cascade delete. Personally I don't allow it to be used on a database I manage as it can have bad side effects when someone needs to delete a record with a million child records. If a product has orders, you should not be able to delete it at all. What you should have is a field to set a product as active. Then inactivate products with orders don't delete them. This is why databases should be designed by people (perferably database experts) not frameworks and why the database design should be done before the application design.

Comment: I'd go even further. I'd copy the product details to the OrderDetail. This way your OrderDetails remain unchanged if you ever change a product, like the name or more importantly the price.

Answer (score 2):

to solve this issue, what you need to do is remove the foreign key attribute, and just leave the object referenced as virtual:

here's what I did:

the old code when I had this bug:

```
    public class OperatingSystemType
{
    public int OperatingSystemTypeID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string OperatingSystemName { get; set; }

    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyID")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

the new code after solving this bug:

```
    public class OperatingSystemType
{
    public int OperatingSystemTypeID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string OperatingSystemName { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

then in the seed, you add data like this shown below, as we just add the Company object as one of the parameter value for OperatingSystemType:

```
        protected override void Seed(MyAPPMVC.Infrastructure.MyContext context)
    {
        string myusername = "myuser";
        string MicrosoftName = "Microsoft";

        context.Companies.AddOrUpdate(p => p.CompanyName,
            new Company { CompanyName = MicrosoftName, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = myusername }
            );

        context.SaveChanges();

        Company MicrosoftCompany = context.Companies.Where(p => p.CompanyName == MicrosoftName).SingleOrDefault();

        context.OperationgSystemTypes.AddOrUpdate(p => p.OperatingSystemName,
            new OperatingSystemType { OperatingSystemName = "Windows 7 Professional", Company = MicrosoftCompany, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = myusername },
            new OperatingSystemType { OperatingSystemName = "Windows 8 Professional", Company = MicrosoftCompany, CreatedOn = DateTime.Now, CreatedBy = myusername }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue on EF Core with this piece on code in OnModelCreating:

```
foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
{
    relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
}
```