# Is there a way to model an optional many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way in Entity Framework (and I assume it will be with fluent syntax as data annotations are somewhat limited) to model a many-to-many relationship in which both sides are optional (a 0..M to 0..N relationship)? The use case is this: I would like to allow users to add tags to entities. Tags to entities is a M:N relationship, but neither should be required. That is, a tag can exist that is not applied to any entities and an entity can be untagged. This seems fairly reasonable to me. I can't simply model this using:

```
public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

and

```
public virtual ICollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
```

because each class has other relationships, and I get a "foreign key constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths." I was hoping maybe I could do something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasOptional(t => t.Entities);
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().HasOptional(t => t.Tags);
```

but I am warned that EF is "Unable to determine the principal end of the association." From reading, it seems that such relationships HAVE to have a principal end, but in my case, that's undesirable.

I could add a class to represent the bridge table and handle the mapping manually, but I'd prefer not to clutter the code. I was wondering if there is another way to model this in EF.

To fill in a bit more detail, there is also an Author class (which amounts to Users). Authors and tags are 1:M and Authors to Entities are also 1:M. So of course, the problem is that the Entities class occurs twice in the cascade tree. Making the Tag/Entity relationship optional would fix this. I could also fix it if there was a way to get to Tags through Entities, but since Tags can exist without being connected to an entity, I figured that would be impossible.

Here's a summary of the related code:

```
public class Author
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:

Using `.HasMany().WithMany()` as suggested below gives me this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TagEntities] (
    [Tag_Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Entity_Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TagEntities] PRIMARY KEY ([Tag_Id], [Entity_Id])
)
```

but what I WANT is for Tag_Id and Entity_Id to be nullable on this table. Maybe this model doesn't make as much sense as I thought?? Can you have a bridge table where both sides are nullable?

Comment: It makes no sense for Tag_Id or Entity_Id to be nullable. Tags without Entities will not have their Tag_Id in that table. Entities without tags will not have their Entity_Id in that table.

Comment: True, I see what you mean. A tag does not have to be connected to an entity, but if it's not connected, it just won't be in this table. But when it IS connected both ends are required. So is there another way to do what I'm after? Maybe I need to set `WillCascadeOnDelete()`?

Comment: Of course both ends are required when it IS connected. Let's say Tag 1 is connection to Entities 1 and 2. That will put two records in that table: 1-1 and 1-2. I don't really see what's the problem with that. Entity Framework will also automatically cascade deletes with m:n mappings.

Comment: It's not a problem - it's what I want to happen, but as you mention below, "both the cascaded deletes (Author -> Tag and Author -> Entity) can possible try to delete the same records in TagEntity." So EF won't let me do it. There has to be a way around this...

Comment: This (the cyclic cascading deletes) is not an EF but SQL problem. It usually is an indication that you might want to reconsider your data model.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasMany(t => t.Entities)
    .WithMany(t => t.Tags);
```

Instead of

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasOptional(t => t.Entities);
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().HasOptional(t => t.Tags);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that. The problem is the XML doc in Visual Studio says `WithMany(TTarget)` configures the relationship to be optional:many with no navigation property on the other side of the relationship. But I'd like to have that navigation property. But maybe the nature of navigation properties is that they indicate required relationships. I'm not really sure. Obviously, I can use `Include()` to get the other side. This may be the best/only answer, but I'm gonna wait a bit longer and see if there's something else.

Comment: Incidentally, I just tried this and still get the "cycles or multiple cascade paths" error. I thought maybe that was because I needed to get rid of one of the ICollection<> navigation properties, but of course, if I do that, there's no way to specify it in the HasMany/WithMany.

Comment: Just discovered I was reading the wrong overload of `WithMany()`. So maybe I want `.HasMany(t => t.Entities).WithOptional(t => t.Tags);`?

Comment: The "cycles or multiple cascade paths" error is because of something else. Have a look at my answer for this question on cyclic cascade paths: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864704/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-on-table-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade/11866202#11866202

Comment: Are you sure? Author -> Tag -> TagEntity and Author -> Entity -> TagEntity are both cascade paths that end at the same table. And I didn't have this problem till I added the Author/Tag relationship.

Comment: That's because when you delete an author, this will also delete his tags and entities. Now both the cascaded deletes (Author -> Tag and Author -> Entity) can possible try to delete the same records in TagEntity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the RIGHT answer, but I solved this by creating a base class called DbEntity that other classes inherited from. So now Author has just:

```
// Both entities and tags are part of this collection
public virtual List<DbEntity> Entities { get; set; }
```

Both "Entities" (which has special meaning in my code) and "Tags" subclass DbEntity. This eliminated the multiple cascade paths while preserving the navigation properties, although I do need to do this:

```
author.Entities.OfType<Tag>();
```

or

```
author.Entities.OfType<Entity>();
```

to get specific sets of entities.