# Required-to-required relationship with cascading delete (Entity Framework)

Tags: database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

In my db model I got a table of Jobs and a table of JobResults.

The model definitions look the following:

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual JobResult Result { get; set; }
}

public class JobResult
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

And the fluent API configuring the relationships is the following:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Result)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Job)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

   modelBuilder.Entity<JobResult>()
            .HasKey(x => x.JobId);
```

As you see, it's a required-to-required relationship where they both share the Id of Job as primary key.
When a Job is deleted I obviously want the JobResult to be deleted as well (which is why I added the WillCascadeOnDelete()).

However when I update my database with the definitions above I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.JobResults_dbo.Jobs_JobId'
>   on table 'JobResults' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint. See previous
>   errors.

This exclusively happens when I include the WillCascadeOnDelete().

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure these are your only tables referring to Jobresult or job ? Because I just tried your code and it gave no errors at all. You know the default is to activate cascade delete, and if there are 2 tables referring to the same table then 2 times cascade delete is a problem

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by a possible cyclic cascading delete. This can happen in many forms, but it comes down to a record being deleted by two or more cascading delete rules in one time, so I ussume that you have another relationship where  the `Job` entity is involved, and when you delete a record from the `Job` table, it is possible this delete will end trying to delete for both side the same record in another Table.

I suggest you take a look to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864704/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-on-table-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade) and check if you don't have a situation like the example that is showed in the @KristofClaes' answer.

You can avoid such ambiguous delete paths by either disabling cascading delete using [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620#CascadeDelete) or by defining some of the relationships as optional (with a nullable foreign key).

Comment: I think this is the only viable explanation. Therefore I deleted my suggestion which was wrong and upvoted yours