# Entity Framework Code first Foreign Key may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am getting the following error:

> Additional information: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.Clubs_dbo.Addresses_Address_Id' on table 'Clubs' may cause
>   cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Club model

```
public class Club
{

    [Key]
    public int ClubId { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Club name is required")]
    [DisplayName("Club name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Address Model

```
public class Address
{
    //[Required]
    [Key]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
    [DisplayName("Address")]
    public string FirstLine { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Town is required")]
    [DisplayName("Town")]
    public string Town { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "County is required")]
    [DisplayName("County")]
    public string County { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8)]
    [DisplayName("Postcode")]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

It is a one to one relationship.

I have tried several solutions to resolve this problem, removing the required data annotation.

I also tried this code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

}
```

I tried this solution also:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasKey(a => a.AddressId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Club>().HasRequired(a => a.Address);
  }
```

Where am I going wrong and how do I correct it?

Comment: Are there any other keys in your database that could be causing this error? I feel like there is some additional information that is missing here.

Comment: Hi David,
I have another 11 models, but VS is throwing up the error regarding the Clubs & Address models. Should I put up the other 11 models?

Comment: EF throws that error because your database has thrown that. It's an SQL Server error for cascading references. Is has something to do with Clubs and Address models as you have guessed but might have been thrown due to some previous cascading relationship. The whole point here is that SQL server is getting confused if when deleting an Address it should also delete the Club record but the Club might already have been deleted due to some previous cascade effect on both tables. Paste here ALL relationships from these two entities and all of their code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the relationship you have between `Club` and `Address` is not one-to-one, it is one-to-many. The correct way to configure this relationship is this way:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Club>().HasRequired(a => a.Address).WithMany();
```

Now, getting back to your problem, that exception is caused when you have multiple paths of cascade deletes.If the foreign key on the dependent entity is not nullable (like your case), then Code First sets cascade delete on the relationship. So I ussume that you have another relationship where  the `Club` entity is involved, and when you delete a record from the `Clubs` table, it is possible this delete will end trying to delete for both side the same record in the `Addresses` Table.

I suggest you take a look to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864704/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-on-table-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade) and check if you have a situation like the example that is showed in the @KristofClaes' answer.

You can avoid such ambiguous delete paths by either disabling cascading delete using [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620#CascadeDelete) or by defining some of the relationships as optional (with a nullable foreign key). For example using Fluent Api you could configure your relationship as I show below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Club>().HasRequired(a => a.Address).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```